# Is there a "simple" answer for this system of equations in *different* natural numbers $R,S,T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I have the following system of equations
$$ \begin{array} {} 
 4ST&+&0R&+&1S&+&1T&=&aR \\
 4TR&+&1R&+&0S&+&1T&=&bS \\
 4RS&+&1R&+&1S&+&0T&=&cT \\
\end{array}
$$
where $R,S,T$ are *different* natural numbers>1 and I want to show there are no solutions for coefficients $a,b,c$ from natural numbers.
Unfortunately there are the nonlinear terms $ST,RS,RT$ in this, so I cannot do a simple matrix-version of it (and solution by formal inversion) , on the other hand it is very tedious to find an expression only in, say, $T$ by the common handling of expanding and substituting for $R$ and $S$, say.
Perhaps it is (relatively) easy to say somehting about it because the definitions allows for instance to assume an order $R \lt S \lt T$ - but I just don't see it at the moment...
*(additional remark: originally this stems from a question for divisibility: is the lhs divisible by the rhs in each line and I introduced the coefficients $a,b,c$ to make a (possibly invertible) diophantine system out of it. Later I want to expand this to more unknowns so optimally the argumentation should be somehow generalizable)*

***Q:*** Is there still a convenient way to determine the existence or nonexistence of a solution?

Comment: Pick any two of your equations and use them to substitute into the third. Each equation you have has a single variable on the right with no copies of that variable on the left.

Comment: @John: hmm, inserting R introduces S and T on the left and inserting S introduces R and T on the left. I'm left with a quadratic (or cubic?) in two variables... SO I've to proceed the same way and arrive at a complicated cubic equation which is tedius to expand to a formal solution. I hoped there is a simpler way for arguing for the possibility of a solution in natural numbers...